# how to pass any method as a parameter for another function

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, parameter-passing

In class A, I have

```
internal void AFoo(string s, Method DoOtherThing)
{
    if (something)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
        DoOtherThing();
}
```

Now I need to be able to pass `DoOtherThing` to `AFoo()`. My requirement is that `DoOtherThing` can have any signature with return type almost always void. Something like this from Class B,

```
void Foo()
{
    new ClassA().AFoo("hi", BFoo);
}

void BFoo(//could be anything)
{

}
```

I know I can do this with `Action` or by implementing delegates (as seen in many other SO posts) but how could this be achieved if signature of the function in Class B is unknown??

Comment: How would you call the function if it has parameters?

Comment: @erikH which function from the lot?

Comment: @nawfal ??? I mean for instance DoSomething(int,string)  as method, would've need some values as arguments...

Comment: @erikH Yes, and I would like to pass it like `new ClassA().AFoo("hi", BFoo("", 0));` if at all its possible. Hope you got my requirement, but I dont know a way out to solve..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a `delegate` instance; `Action` would work fine:

```
internal void AFoo(string s, Action doOtherThing)
{
    if (something)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
        doOtherThing();
}
```

If `BFoo` is parameterless it will work as written in your example:

```
new ClassA().AFoo("hi", BFoo);
```

If it needs parameters, you'll need to supply them:

```
new ClassA().AFoo("hi", () => BFoo(123, true, "def"));
```

Comment: pure brilliance, in one go as I see... more remarks after compiling :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an **Action** or **Func** if you need a return value.

Action:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Func:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T Runner<T>(Func<T> funcToRun)
{
    //Do stuff before running function as normal
    return funcToRun();
}
```

Usage:

```
var ReturnValue = Runner(() => GetUser(99));
```

I use this for error handling on my MVC site.