# C# how to pass 'any' function as a parameter to another function

Tags: c#

i have 5 datafunctions which all return the same type of object (`List<source>`)

Now i have to publish them in a WCF in which i have to surround the called code with all kind of error handling code (about 50 lines).

So i thought: because the code (51 lines) is all the same except the one line to get the data, just create one function with all the errorhandling a pass the function to get the data as a parameter to that function.

So i have these functions:

```
GetAllSources() : List<Source>
GetAllSourcesByTaskId(int taskId) : List<Source>
GetAllSourcesByTaskIdPersonId(int taskId, int personId) : List<Source>
GetAllSourcesByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate): List<Source>
```

and i want be able to pass them as a parameter to a function.

How should i declare the called function?

ps
i've read this one
[how to pass any method as a parameter for another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638547/how-to-pass-any-method-as-a-parameter-for-another-function)
but it uses an Action object which can't return anything (as far as i understand) and i want to return a List

Comment: Use `Func` in the place of `Action`.

Comment: The given functions all take different parameters, how do you plan to supply the right parameters?

Comment: @Roger I tried that, but i couldn't get it to work. It seemed to me that a func has only one signature (correct me if i'm wrong) so when i declare a func for the `GetAllSources()` i can't pass the `GetAllSourcesByTaskId(int taskId)`?

Comment: @GregL: i don't know, but i thought i could do something like this: `List<Source> = GetDataFromGenericErrorHhandlingFunction(Dataservice.GetAllSourcesByTaskId(6));`

Comment: @Michel Your example just calls the `Dataservice.GetAllSourcesByTaskId()` function and passes the return value to the `GetDataFromGenericErrorHhandlingFunction()` method. That is easy stuff. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<Source> WithErrorHandling(Func<List<Source>> func)
{
    ...
    var ret = func();
    ...
    return ret;
 }
```

Usage:

```
 var taskId = 123;
 var res = WithErrorHandling(() => { GetAllSourcesByTaskId(taskId); });
```

Comment: Excellent! What i did not do, and made it fail, was this: `() => { GetAllSourcesByTaskId(taskId); }`; instead i did this: `GetAllSourcesByTaskId(taskId);`. That does work when you have a function with no parameters (so this works `GetAllSources` as parameter) but as i now know, not when you pass in a funciton with a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) which can take many input parameters are return a value:

```
Func<T1, T2, TResult>
```

In your case something like this could work:

```
public List<Source> GetList(Func<List<Source>> getListMethod) {
    return getListMethod();
}
```

Then call using

```
GetList(() => GetAllSources());
GetList(() => GetAllSourcesByTaskIdPersonId(taskId, personId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just pass the List as an argument into your method, might be a bit tidier?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't say anything about the code inside these functions, but if you use linq inside, than your approach is definitely not the best one. 
You should use something like this:

```
IQueriable<SomeType> GetAllSources()
{
    return (from source in sources select ...);
}

IQueriable<SomeType> GetAllSourcesByTaskId(int taskId)
{
    return (GetAllSources()).Where(source => source.TaskId == taskId);
}
```